# How add "-" before each capital letter in a string

Tags: android

How can i add "-" before each capital letter of my string apart from first capital     letter of my string.

I have a string like this "HelloWorldMyNameIsCarl" and i am using this

```
"HelloWorldMyNameIsCarl".replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Lu})", "$1-$2")
```

it's working fine.

solution is

```
"Hello_World_My_Name_Is_Carl"
```

but for "THisForNEWTest" it's not working and solution is

```
"T-His-For-NEw-Test"
```

But i want

```
"T-His-For-N-Ew-Test"
```

please suggest me what i do for this problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if there is a too complex problem for regular expressions, you can always use normal programming. it might even be a little bit more efficient :

```
public static String doIt(String input)
  {
  int size=input.length();
  if(size==0)
    return "";
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(size);
  sb.append(input.charAt(0));
  for(int i=1;i<size;++i)
    {
    char c=input.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
      sb.append('-');
    sb.append(c);
    }
  return sb.toString();
  }
```

in any case, for regular expressions tests, you can check out [**this website**](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

so, for regular expressions, the solution can be:

```
return input.charAt(0)+input.substring(1).replaceAll("(\\p{Lu})","-$1");
```

Comment: @deep you're welcomed. i've changed the code a bit with Character.isUpperCase instead of checking values, after seeing "Vamshi" solution. i do the checkings because i'm still an ex-C programmer...

Comment: @deep i've also updated the answer with a regular expression one.

Comment: actually the second solution isn't full - you need to check if the input string is empty, and if so, return "" . happy holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just doing this:

```
replaceAll("(\\p{Lu})", "-$1").replaceAll("^-", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
String test = "THisForNEwTest";
int size = test.length();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 if(size!=0)
   sb.append(test.charAt(0));

     for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(test.charAt(i))){
            sb.append("-"+test.charAt(i));
        }else{
            sb.append(test.charAt(i));
        }           
        }
System.out.println("result is::::"+sb.toString());
```

Comment: i've already provided a very similar code. also, you didn't handle the case of empty string, and by concatenating things you create new temporary strings...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String function(String str) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        List<Integer> capital = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
                capital.add(i);

        int capIndex = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < str.length(); y++) {

            if(x < capital.size())
                capIndex = capital.get(x);

            if (y == 0) {
                result.append(str.charAt(y));
                x++;
            } else if(y == capIndex){
                result.append("-" + str.charAt(y));
                x++;
            } else {
                if(str.charAt(y) != ' ')
                    result.append(str.charAt(y));
            }
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```